# How to merge or extend a volume in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a volume vol1 of type ext4(256G) and it's almost full. I have another volume vol2 of type ext4 and its totally free.

```
sdb                            LVM2_member       
└─hana2-hanalv                 ext4              
sdc                            LVM2_member      
└─hana2--extend-hanalv--extend ext4
```

and

```
 LV            VG             LSize   
  hanalv        hana2         256.00g
  hanalv-extend hana2-extend 256.00g
```

is there a way to merge the second one with the first one? Could you please list some steps that I follow, I am not good in Linux...

Thank you

Comment: If you are not good than dont do it, Because you will do mistakes and lose your data. Back it up before playing. And explain what devices/partitions you want to merge.

Comment: Show the output of the command lsblk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you don't know, with what are playing, you risk your data. Although I think you aren't too far to know it enough well.

If your second partition (which is on sdc) is totally free, then you can delete it. **Do it only if it is really empty!!!**

First, you can eliminate the vg hana2-extend.

```
vgchange -an hana2-extend
```

Now hana2-extend is turned off.

You re-create on it the physical volume:

```
pycreate /dev/sdc
```

...and you can add to your original volume group, hana2:

```
vgextend hana2 /dev/sdc
```

Now you have only a single volume group, hana2, which is using both your sdb and sdc hard disks.

In the next step, you can extend the logical volume hanalv to the whole volume group:

```
lvextend -n hanalv -L <extentnum>
```

...where extentnum is the total number of the extents on the current hana2 volume group. You can get this with the `vgdisplay hana2` command.

Now that the partition is enough big, you can resize also the filesystem on it:

```
resize2fs /dev/hana2/hanalv
```

...and so it it. You can do the last step even without unmounting the filesystem, because ext4 is smart and it can be grown online.

**Again: do it only after you backuped everything.**

Comment: vgchange -an hana2-extend
  Logical volume hana2-extend/hanalv-extend contains a filesystem in use.
  Can't deactivate volume group "hana2-extend" with 1 open logical volume(s)

Comment: @SalhiFadhel You said it is free, then you can first unmount it.

Comment: --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               hana2
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  3

  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               511.99 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              131070
  Alloc PE / Size       65535 / 256.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       65535 / 256.00 GiB
which one to use instean of extentnum??

Comment: @SalhiFadhel Total PE. PE means: physical extents. 1 extent is 4 MB.

Comment: @SalhiFadhel No. lvextend -n hanalv -L 1234567, where this 1234567 shows, how many physical extents do you want to give to the hanalv. I suggest to read an LVM tutorial.